Subject: Exploring Dynamic Text Replacement for GIFs and Animations
I am currently working on a project that involves dynamic text replacement on GIFs, similar to what services like Memix ( https://www.memix.com/ ) offer, where users can replace text in GIFs in real time.
I’ve experimented with Lottie animations, but the results haven't been satisfactory. Specifically, After Effects does not provide all the animation effects (such as blending, mash, and others) needed when exporting to Lottie JSON via the Bodymovin plugin.
Could anyone suggest any alternative methods or tools that could help me achieve high-quality dynamic text replacement on GIFs with advanced animation effects?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
